# Failed to iterate data with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

It is my first contact with REACT.
Trying to iterate a JSON in react tells me that .**map is not a function**.

***My iterator code is:***

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
// Importar cliente Axios
import clienteAxios from '../../config/axios';


    function Clientes () {

        const [clientes, guardarClientes] = useState([]);

        const consultarAPI = async() => {
            // console.log('Consultando...');
            const clientesConsulta = await clienteAxios.get('/clientes');
            // console.log(clientesConsulta.data);

            // Colocar el resultado en el State
            guardarClientes(clientesConsulta.data);
        }

        //  Use effect es similar a componentdidmount y willmount
        useEffect( () => {
            consultarAPI();
        },[]);

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h2>Clientes</h2>
                {console.log(clientes)}


                <ul className="listado-clientes">
                    {clientes.map(cliente => {
                       console.log(clientes)
                })}
                </ul>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }

    export default Clientes;
```

The resul in  console is a Array of Objetcs

```
clientes": [
        {
            "_id": "5edd409674d46d3570b34e69",
            "nombre": "jon",
            "apellido": "perex",
            "empresa": "Leka.NET",
            "email": "as64@fs.com",
            "telefono": "782555555",
            "__v": 0
        },
```

With **clientesConsulta.data** console:

```
__proto__: Object

    __proto__: Object

    clientes: Array(5)}
       clientes: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
       __proto__: Object
    clientes: Array(5)}
       clientes: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
       __proto__: Object
```

With **clientesConsulta.data.clientes** console:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Up to this point the data enters well, it is verified. The flaw is that I don't know how to iterate.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is `clientes` actually an array? I don't see where it's being set. You could only use the `.map()` method if it was an array.

Comment: It sounds like `clientes` is `undefined`. You can check this by debugging your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, yes I do a client console, it gives me all the data correctly.
They are in an array of objects.

Comment: Hi Code-Apprentice; I think you mean the second chunk of code, where you can see the structure of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello and thanks to all who have intervened in the doubt.**
I already have the answer. I put down the code of the solution.
It was to get the iterator to an external function and also as Pirhan said, it was necessary to take the data in `saveClients (clientsConsult.data.clients);`.
The code is:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
// Importar cliente Axios
import clienteAxios from '../../config/axios';


function Clientes () {
    // Trabajar con el State
    // clientes = State
    // guardarClientes = Funcion para guardar el State
    const [clientes, guardarClientes] = useState({});
    //Query a la API
    const consultarAPI = async() => {
        // console.log('Consultando...');
        const clientesConsulta = await clienteAxios.get('/clientes');
        // console.log(clientesConsulta.data.clientes);

        // Colocar el resultado en el State
        guardarClientes(clientesConsulta.data.clientes);
    }

    //  Use effect es similar a componentdidmount y willmount
    useEffect( () => {
        consultarAPI();
    }, [] );


    function createArray(clientes) {
        if (clientes && clientes.length > 0) {
          return clientes.map(cliente => console.log('hola')
          );
        }
        return [];
      }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2>Clientes</h2>
            {/* {console.log(clientes)} */}
            {/* {console.log(guardarClientes)} */}

            <ul className="listado-clientes">
                {createArray(clientes)}
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Clientes;
```

Once again thanks to those of you who have intervened and especially to user177767 who has put me on the track. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an asynchronous call and you are iterating within the return, set a conditional to make sure the data has actually been set to state like so:

```
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h2>Clientes</h2>
                {console.log(clientes)}


                <ul className="listado-clientes">
                    {clientes ? clientes.map(cliente => {
                       console.log(clientes)
                }) : ''}
                </ul>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
```

EDIT: Also, change `console.log(clientes)` to `console.log(cliente)` to see individual elements

Comment: Hi AttemptedMastery,Thank you very much.
I've tried it but it doesn't work
it gives me the same error

Comment: Sorry for my late response!  I was getting home from work.  I can get on later and try to help you.

Comment: I think you would want to check both `clients && clients.length ? ... : ''`, because `clientes` will be true if `clientes` is an empty object too

Comment: Hi AttemptedMastery, yes please, I have been working so far and I could not answer thank you very much friend

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to add ".clientes" at the end of `guardarClientes(clientesConsulta.data);`. It looks like it should be
`guardarClientes(clientesConsulta.data.clientes);` Is this the case?

Comment: I have tried it and the result of the search is clearer.
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
I've put some info on it.
but still not iterate: (((((
I don't have much idea where to attack the problem.
Thank you very much for your help